# Meteor accounts-password reset token expiry

Tags: meteor

Trying to figure out if the token generated by a call to `Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail()` will ever expire. I can't find any further documentation on the `accounts-password` package beyond what's in the main Meteor docs--any pointers?

Link to Meteor docs on `accounts-password`:
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_sendresetpasswordemail

ETA: per Sindis' comment and a little experimenting, it appears that tokens do not expire after a certain timeframe.

Comment: I don't think so, it adds token to meter.users collection, if you want it to expire over time you probably should do it explicitly

Comment: Tokens may not expire but when they are used they do get removed. Worth noting since it was not clear in any of the documentation.

Comment: Interestingly, the error message in the callback from a call to `Accounts.resetPassword` can contain a message `Token expired [403]` in some situations.

Comment: the meaning of "expired" seems to be that the token was already used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems linke it didn't expire until Meteor version 1.4.

Now it is listed as breaking change, expiring after 3 days: [Meteor 1.4 Enroll Breaking change](https://guide.meteor.com/1.4-migration.html#tokens-expire)